# How to fix compiler error when try to initialise a std::array from a non const size

Tags: c++, templates, stdarray

I know I can use a vector, but I don't need the extra features of a vector so wanted to use a std::array.  The problem I have is that I get the size of the array from the user - from stdin.  Then I know the size and initialise the array from there.

I tried the following code but get the compiler error as shown.  I also tried constexpr with fsize.

How can I edit my code to create a std::array from a size not known at compile time?

```
int main() {

  int size;
  cin >> size;

  const int fsize = size;
  // below line compile error
  std::array<int, fsize> items;
}
```

compile error:

```
error C2971: 'std::array' : template parameter '_Size' : 'fsize' : a local variable cannot be used as a non-type argument
 : see declaration of 'std::array'
   see declaration of 'fsize'
```

Comment: You can't. Template non-type parameters must be compile-time constants.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead:`std::vector<int> items(fsize);`

Comment: The size of `std::array` must be determined at compile time. If you need dynamic arrays, `std::vector` is preferable.

Comment: To generalize, templates generate code which is compiled with the rest of the program. If the compiler doesn't have the information it needs, it will tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I edit my code to create a std::array from a size not known at compile time?

You can't. `std::array` is a fixed-sized array, it's size must be a constant known at compile-time.

To make a dynamic array whose size is not known until runtime, you must use `new[]` instead:

```
int *items = new int[fsize];
...
delete[] items;
```

Preferably, you should use `std::vector` instead, which handles that for you:

```
std::vector<int> items(fsize);
```

If you don't want to use `std::vector`, you can use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> items(new int[fsize]);
```

or

```
auto items = std::make_unique<int[]>(fsize);
```